# (Error)No Persistence provider for EntityManager named myConnectionDB

Tags: java, oracle, xml, hibernate, jpa

Al tratar de mapear la base de datos HR de oracle me sale ese error y pues desconozco qué tengo mal en el archivo persistence.xml que adjunto acá. Estoy trabajando con java y hibernate.

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence

http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"

version="2.1">


<persistence-unit name="myConnectionDB" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

<class>com.prueba.dominio.Persona</class>

<properties>
  <!-- Configuring JDBC properties -->
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE" />
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="hr" />
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="Mojojojo89" />
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />

  <!-- Hibernate properties -->
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
  <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
  <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />


</properties>
```

El driver usado para la conexión a la base de datos es ojdbc7

Quisiera saber qué configuración debo cambiar del archivo persistence.xml o si el problema está en el pom.

Agradezco su colaboración.